# Fire event when iphone app is in background?

Tags: iphone, enterprise, multitasking, background-process

We can register iPhone app to run in background when using location/music functionality. My question is can we fire an even based on a location update? eg: Send lat/long to a server when i reach a certain predefined lat/long in the background without launching the app?

I would not mind using Enterprise solution if its of any help.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can be done. Check for details from Apple on [Getting the User’s Location](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the **significant location change** API, it should provide what you want, albeit not very accurately.
http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/07/22/iphone-background-gps-accurate-to-500-meters-not-enough-for-foot-traffic/

Comment: +1 wow they have done some pretty exhaustive research. I was looking at a foot traffic based app guess the accuracy level in the background wont be enough. Will have to look further into this.

Answer (score 0):

yeah that's possible. If you use the locationmanager and you get a new location through the delegate, your code there will be executed without opening the app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this API

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
     //write code here
}
```